# Mongoose - find documents that match one or more conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have three documents that look like this

```json
{
            "name": "X1",
            "location": {
                "country": "Ireland",
                "state": "Dublin",
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "X2",
            "location": {
                "country": "Ireland",
                "state": "Dublin",
                "address": ""
            },
        },
        {
            "name": "C3",
            "location": {
                "country": "United States of America",
                "state": "California",
                "address": "San Jose"
            },
```

I am trying to implement a filtering functionality to show documents based on multiple locations.
so, the endpoint URL looks like this for example `http://localhost:3000/api/companies/stacks?state[]=Dublin&country[]=United%20States%20of%20America`

So, it should return the three documents that are shown above, yet it only returns this document

```
        {
            "name": "C3",
            "location": {
                "country": "United States of America",
                "state": "California",
                "address": "San Jose"
            },
```

Here is the source code, I am using Mongoose mainly.

```js
        //Filtering by location
        if ('country' in req.query) {
            const countries = [...country]
            conditions['location.country']={$in:countries}
        }
        if ('state' in req.query) {
            const states = [...state]
            conditions['location.states'] = { $in: states }
        }
        const doc = await model
            .find(conditions)
            .sort({ p: -1, _id: 1 })
            .lean()
            .exec()
```

I understood that it returns the document that matches the `country` parameter, but I don't understand why it doesn't also fetch the other documents that has `Dublin` in `states`?

Edit: I also tried to use `$or` operator like that

```
find({
  $or:[
    {'location.country':'United States of America'},
    {'location.states':'Dublin'}
    ]
})
```

Yet it also, returned the document that matches the country only. I thought about using `aggregates` but I am not sure if it is going to help me in my case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure it is `states` instead of `state`?

Comment: `states` should be `state` for this to work

Comment: Check [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HTQerf6AdKg)

Comment: @ray forgive me for such a silly mistake, it works now thank you!